# Does English have a common parlance demarcation between inclusive disjunction and exclusive disjunction?

Tags: terminology

Distinguishing between *inclusive or* and *exclusive or* in logic is useful. Is there already an ascribed way of using each of these operators in everyday speech in English?

Answer (score 2):

I agree with McCawley that the English "or" is always inclusive.  Sometimes extraneous circumstances make the "both" interpretation unreasonable, giving the false impression that there is an exclusive sense.  I think that argument is probably in McCawley's book **What linguists always wanted to know about logic, but were afraid to ask**.

Comment: Me too. There may be different phenomena that force exclusive _or_, just as there are that force inclusive vs exclusive _we_, but that doesn't mean they're otherwise distinguished.